# "Бедные дети!" Какой это тип предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Бедные дети! Как мне их жаль!

Это двусоставное предложение с инверсией? Или это односоставное предложение?

Answer (score 1):

*Бедные дети!* - конечно, односоставное. Никаких инверсий. Это есть в школьном учебнике, поэтому "доказательств" и ссылок давать не буду. Ну, второе тоже односоставное, подлежащего-то нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но все-таки приведите, пожалуйста, ссылки на подобные примеры.

Comment: А чем школьный учебник не устраивает? Здесь нет никаких тонкостей. Унылая пора, звенящая тишина, бедные дети и т.п. – если эти словосочетания оформить как предложения, то это будут номинативные предложения.

Comment: Я согласен, что в некотором контексте это назывные (номинативные) предложения. Например:"1918 год. Москва. Голодные беспризорники." Здесь же, как в случае "Славная осень!", не все просто. Вот [ссылка] (http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-025.htm), где говорится о двусмысленности подобной конструкции.

Comment: Насколько я понял, и такие оценочные предложения автор считает целесообразным рассматривать как номинативные.